# has keypressevent a method that distinguishing pressing the key continuously

Tags: qt, keypress

has "KeyPressEvent" a method that distinguishing pressing the key continuously.i mean if user keep a key of keyboard and don't release it soon, how i can understand it?i want it for "super_mario" game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `bool QKeyEvent::isAutoRepeat () const`
>
> Returns true if this event comes from an auto-repeating key; returns
>   false if it comes from an initial key press. Note that if the event is
>   a multiple-key compressed event that is partly due to auto-repeat,
>   this function could return either true or false indeterminately.

QKeyEvent instance is passed as the `keyPressEvent()` param.